# Can I create a generic method with generic input TInput and generic output TOut in c#

Tags: c#, generics

Can I create a generic method with generic input(TInput) and generic output(TOutput) in c# or any alternative for this kind of scenario?

Comment: What do you mean by 'generic output', the return type or an `out` parameter?

Comment: Return type for a generic method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean a generic method? Just use the generic `<T>` behind the declaration of the method name, like: *(ofcourse the input type specification is unnecessary in this example, because the Convert.ChangeType uses an object as parameter)*

```
public static TOutput ConvertTo<TInput, TOutput>(TInput input)
{
    return (TOutput)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(TOutput));
}
```

Usage:

```
int myInt = 10;
double myDouble = ConvertTo<int, double>(myInt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Here is an example:

```
using System;

namespace GenericInOut {

    class Test<In, Out> {
        public Out Afunc(In x) {
            return default;
            }
        }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var t = new Test<int, string>();
            Console.WriteLine($"output is default for string {t.Afunc(3)}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Is that the extent of your question?  You may want to be more specific if you want greater detail in your answers.